# Replace value of ngModel if not exists

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel

I have a conditional field in a form like this:

```
<mat-form-field *ngIf="model.personIsMarried === 'Yes'">
    <input type="number" 
      matInput id="personSpouseAge" 
      [(ngModel)]="model.personSpouseAge"
      name="personSpouseAge" 
      placeholder="Spouse Age"
  </mat-form-field>
```

If the user is not married the value of `model.personSpouseAge` is `undefined`. What I want is to set the value of `model.personSpouseAge` to the `model.personAge` field that was previously filled, for example:

The person filling the form is age 27 and is not married, so the `model.personSpouseAge` field value will also be `27`.

I hope to be clear. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @danday74 answer is correct. But in general when person is not married you should not enable this textfield at first place. Second making SpouseAge same as PersonAge eventhough he is not married is completely miss guiding and new person will find it hard to under stand. Better solution would be to keep 2 text box one for person age and another for spouseage. Disable sponseage textbox when person is not married

Comment: The field is hidden if the person is not married, but I MUST pass a value there as is required for an backend script, I now is not optimal but it is what it is. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In html:

```
[ngModel]="model.personSpouseAge"
(ngModelChange)="setPersonSpouseAge(model)"
```

In .ts:

```
setPersonSpouseAge(model) {
  model.personSpouseAge = model.personSpouseAge || model.personAge
}
```